# Regex from textbox string issue

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex that I use in C# and it is working if I do :

```
Regex prompt = new Regex((@"\[.*@.*\][\$|\#]"));
```

But when I put the Regex in a textbox i.e I put the following `(@"\[.*@.*\][\$|\#]")` 
in the textbox including the parenthesis, and then I do :

```
Regex prompt = new Regex(textBox1.Text);  // <----- That is not working.
```

I also tried:

```
Regex prompt = new Regex(@textBox1.Text); // <----- That is not working also
```

So was wondering if I may have some character I need to escape or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not include the parentheses. You should be entering `[.@.][\$|#]` in the textbox. Then in code do:

```
Regex prompt = new Regex(textBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Tried what you wrote and was not working... but I got it working using : \[.*@.*\][\$|\#] 

Thanks for the quick help :)